# Jasperreports server installation with existing Tomcat - Unable to bind port

Tags: tomcat, installation, exists, 32-bit, jasperserver

I am trying to install Jasperreports 5.6.1 on Windows 32bit. Any newer version is not available yet. In the installation wizard I have entered both existing components: existing Tomcat and existing PostgreSQL server. It asks for the tomcat port, chosen is default 8080. Next button reports error: "Unable to bind the server port. Please make sure that Tomcat is not running."
I expect it must be running in this installation. But the error message is the same, it doesn't matter if the Tomcat7 service is running or not. In explorer I can verify (http://localhost:8080) if the service is really running or not. What is wrong? Is it such bug in installation exe-file and I am the first user stricken by it?

Comment: Is it possible that when it asks for the tomcat port, it is asking for the port of the existing installation, (whereas 8080 is the default port if Jasper Reports would be installed as an independent installation)

Comment: I want JR to be installed as a new application in my existing Tomcat, that is already running on 8080. It will allow better maintenance, especially with memory limits problems I have encountered.

Comment: OK. Good luck solving it....